# Parsing OSM XML data with python with specific sub tags

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, xml-parsing, openstreetmap, elementtree

I am trying to parse way tags out from an osm XML file for example I want to search through the entire xml file and when a way tag has a k value of bridge it saves the entire way tag into a csv file with all the other ways that have bridge tags.

```
 <way id="108534076" visible="true" version="1" changeset="7866393" timestamp="2011-04-15T02:42:51Z" user="richlv" uid="47892">
  <nd ref="1245024935"/>
  <nd ref="1245025038"/>
  <tag k="bridge" v="yes"/>
  <tag k="highway" v="service"/>
 </way>
```

here is the code I have written so far but keep having an AttributeError

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('MER.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for way in root.findall('way'):
    tag = way.find('.//tag')
    if tag.attrib['k'] == 'bridge' and tag.attrib['v'] == 'yes':
        print tag
```

the file I have is very big and I am looking through 4000 way tags for about 34 bridge tags.

[Error Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/598qm.png)

Comment: Post the entire trace so we can see exactly the line and error. Its likely `tag = way.find(..)` what if it doesn't find anything? Then tag is None and boom.

Comment: I added it to the bottom of my post

Comment: Any chance to copy/paste instead of jpeg? For those reading along its `AttributeError: None type object has no attribute 'atrrib'`.

Comment: yeah sorry I am new to this

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that not all `<way>` elements have a `<tag>` underneath. You can fix it by checking

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('MER.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for way in root.findall('way'):
    tag = way.find('.//tag')
    if tag and tag.attrib['k'] == 'bridge' and tag.attrib['v'] == 'yes':
        print tag
```

Or you could jump into xpath and let the xml doc do the work for you

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('MER.xml')
for tag in tree.findall('//way//tag[@k="bridge"][@v="yes"]'):
    print tag
```

And for large files, `lxml` is usually faster

```
import lxml.etree
tree = lxml.etree.parse('MER.xml')
for tag in tree.findall('//way//tag[@k="bridge"][@v="yes"]'):
    print tag
```